# Is there a way to append addtiional clients manually to a socket room created by a connected client?

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I'm having difficulties in finding a solution for a scenario when users are mentioned in the comments section. They receive a notification regardless of their online presence.

```
module.exports = function (io) {
    io.on('connect', function (socket) {
         // pre-processing operations to get the users
         let users = ['user1', 'user2', 'user3'];
 
         socket.join('room', () => {
                  // how would I manually join `users` to this room 
         } 
         
         // While broadcasting a message only to those users who were manually joined
         socket.to('room').emit('event', {"message" : "You were mentioned in this conversation"})    

   }
```

Any suggestions, resources to look into?

Comment: How would this work, is this a browser thing, a mobile app a desktop app? Each one has it's own separate solution, but we would need some clarification to point you in the right direction

Comment: When a comment is created or addressed whilst some users are mentioned in the comments. Then these users would receive notifications. This is similar to a real-time notification system. I'm trying to address these with socket.io.

Comment: Its a backend design for both mobile and web applications.

Answer (score 1):

There are scenarios where I want users who are part of the conversation and not using the application.